# localtime() returns a pointer to a structure with uninitialized members

Tags: c, windows, tm, localtime

```c
char datetime[DATETIME_LEN];
time_t timer;
struct tm* tm_info;

timer = time(NULL);
tm_info = localtime(&timer); // debug: tm_info: 0xcccccccccccccccc {tm_sec=??? tm_min=??? tm_hour=??? ...}
if (NULL == tm_info) // debug: 0xffffffffba9b07b0 {tm_sec=??? tm_min=??? tm_hour=??? ...}
{
  return;
}

strftime(datetime, DATETIME_LEN, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", tm_info); // Crush is here
```

At place where tm_info is used,
tm_info's content is

[image: tm_info's content]

Any ideas about why unable to read memory?
Does anyone had the same issue?
By the way, if I use [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), I have no this issue.

Comment: You need to go past the line where the assignment happens in your debugger before you'll see the results.

Comment: @dbush you mean to debug localtime function?

Comment: @dbush is it possible to debug localtime function? I mean VS doesn’t have source code, but it offers me to browse localtime.cpp

Comment: Not in that function, after that call.  In other words, when you step to the `if (NULL == tm_info)` line does it show something different?

Comment: @dbush I added debug info. Nothing anything different

Comment: You probably have undefined behavior elsewhere in your code.  Time to do some debugging.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: It [works for me](https://www.ideone.com/g4HzW1). There must be something you're not telling us. It also works in my Visual Studio, and I suppose that's what you're using too,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, never blame the tool for failure. The function you are asking about has been in use by trillions of software programs since the late 1960s without problem, and today literally runs the world.

[The documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) makes it clear that the result is stored in static storage not controlled by you.

There are two ways to handle this. The first is simply to copy the data out before anything can happen to it.

```
struct tm tm_info = {0};
struct tm * tm_info_p = localtime(&timer);
if (tm_info_p) tm_info = *tm_info_p;
```

That gets you your own local copy of the data.

The other way is to use `localtime_s()` or `localtime_r()`.

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <time.h>

struct tm tm_info;
localtime_s(&timer, &tm_info);
```

C is a fickle beast, and is not very forgiving when you make an error. Sorry.

[edit] Yep, even experienced programmers make dumb mistakes... Thanks **chux**.

Comment: It's not correct answer, but when I tried to follow your advice(struct tm* → struct tm), I understood that 'tm_info' uses undefined struct 'tm'. So, when I added `#include <time.h>` problem has been solved. Thanks for advice!

Comment: `tm_info = *localtime(&timer)` is a problem when `localtime(&timer)` returns `NULL`.